# extract values from field after mongodb query search

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search, extract

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and programming languages in general, not really sure how to achieve the following objective:

I have a mongodb Collection with many documents like the one below, and all of them have the same structure, only varying some values in some fields:

```js
{
    "status": "ok",
        "data": {
        "aqi": 48,
            "idx": 8495,
                "attributions": [
                    {
                        "url": "http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/site/portalweb/",
                        "name": "Consejería de Medio Ambiente y Ordenación del Territorio :: Junta de Andalucía"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "http://www.eea.europa.eu/themes/air/",
                        "name": "European Environment Agency"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://waqi.info/",
                        "name": "World Air Quality Index Project"
                    }
                ],
                    "city": {
            "geo": [
                37.3485317,
                -5.9877044
            ],
                "name": "Bermejales, Sevilla, Spain",
                    "url": "https://aqicn.org/city/spain/andalucia/sevilla/bermejales"
        },
        "dominentpol": "o3",
            "iaqi": {
            "co": {
                "v": 3.2
            },
            "no2": {
                "v": 2.8
            },
            "o3": {
                "v": 47.6
            },
            "p": {
                "v": 1012.1
            },
            "pm10": {
                "v": 4
            },
            "so2": {
                "v": 2.6
            },
            "w": {
                "v": 6.7
            }
        },
        "time": {
            "s": "2019-05-14 12:00:00",
                "tz": "+02:00",
                    "v": 1559487600
        },
        "debug": {
            "sync": "2019-05-14T11:38:05+09:00"
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to achieve, is to extract the value of the fields **"data.time.s"** and **"data.iaqi.co.v"** (for each document on the collection) between two exact dates and put them together in a new array with this exact structure:

**Example:**
"Get all values of ***"co"*** field between dates ***"2019-05-14"*** and ***"2019-05-29"***

**Final Output:**
Date,value
2019-05-14 12:00:00,3.2
2019-05-15 00:00:00,14.5
2019-05-17 05:00:00,1
2019-05-19 20:00:00,2.3
2019-05-28 08:00:00,33.4
2019-05-28 10:00:00,18.8
2019-05-28 12:00:00,11.5
2019-05-28 13:00:00,12.4
2019-05-29 06:00:00,6.4

I tried to search for this question but didn't find anything related.

The farthest I have reached has been getting the two fields needed with the find operator:

```js
db.getCollection("prueba2").find(
    { 
        "data.time.s" : {
            "$gte" : "2019-05-14", 
            "$lte" : "2019-05-29"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "data.iaqi.co.v" : "$data.iaqi.co.v", 
        "data.time.s" : "$data.time.s", 
        "_id" : NumberInt(0)
    }
);
```

But with that operation I get also all the structure from parent fields:

```js
{ 
    "data" : {
        "iaqi" : {
            "co" : {
                "v" : 3.2
            }
        }, 
        "time" : {
            "s" : "2019-05-14 12:00:00"
        }
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "data" : {
        "iaqi" : {
            "co" : {
                "v" : 14.5
            }
        }, 
        "time" : {
            "s" : "2019-05-15 00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
etc etc etc
```

I'm not really sure if the final output that I need to get, can be achieved with just one MongoDB query operation, maybe I need to first extract the data the way I did, and then work with that JSON in Javascript to have a second extraction of those fields in order to generate a final document with that "clean" final output structure I need.

Please if anyone knows how to achieve this, I'm sure many people will need a solution for this in the future.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so, but all methods will have two operations.

First Approach: Write a script may be in python/java that reads two values perform required array creation and update the document.

Second Approach: Use a forEach clause of mongo javascript and read all data and perform updates.

My suggestion would be if this is something you will require on new data also, better write a script that does the operation in memory and then inserts in MongoDB.
This would be faster and hassle-free.

Comment: I need to use the final output data in an HTML page to represent a Chart with HighCharts framework.

Maybe the best option would it be to store the output data in a variable and then point to this variable on the "data" resource from the Highcharts code.